# Como reposicionar barra de menu abaixo do cabeçalho?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

Estou editando um tema de WordPress e gostaria de reposicionar o menu logo abaixo da imagem do *header*, porém, como fazer isto no CSS?

O site ainda não está hospedado na web. Estou modificando o tema antes de instalar tudo. O código referente à barra de menu são esses:

```css
/**************************** MENU***************************/

/*menu topo*/
.menu-topo {width: 100%; height: 50px; background: #B0D6C9; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05); box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.05);}

/*navegacao de topo*/
nav.navegacao ul {float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

/*lista de menu*/
nav.navegacao ul li {position: relative; display: inline-block; margin: 0;     padding:0;  color: #fff;}
nav.navegacao ul li a {color: #fff; line-height: 50px; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 14px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;}

/*quando o item menu está ativo ou no hover*/
nav.navegacao ul li:hover,
nav.navegacao ul li.current-menu-item, 
nav.navegacao ul li.current_page_parent {background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.57);}

nav.navegacao ul li:hover a,
nav.navegacao ul li.current-menu-item a, 
nav.navegacao ul li.current_page_parent a {color: #85C3AE; }

nav.navegacao ul li:hover:after,
nav.navegacao ul li.current-menu-item:after, 
nav.navegacao ul li.current_page_parent:after {color: #fff; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 50%; width: 0; height: 0; margin-left: -5px; vertical-align: middle; content: " "; border-right: 5px solid transparent; border-bottom: 5px solid; border-left: 5px solid transparent;}

/*menu responsivo*/
.menu-responsivo {width: 100%; margin: 8px auto 0; 
 display: none; /*determina que será invisivel de inicio*/
}
```

O tema se chama temabase_mLuv1.1 Não é um tema gratuito disponível no WordPress, mas foi disponibilizado para [download neste site](http://true-luv.com/tema-base-3-0-para-wordpress).

Comment: Podias adicionar o código HTML também?

Comment: Não consigo lhe enviar por aqui porque é grande, mas coloquei aqui:

http://collabedit.com/77639

Comment: É... se calhar é melhor enviar mesmo o link do site se puderes, porque assim eu posso inspecionar os elementos e ver melhor para te dizer ao certo o que precisas modificar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este tema - `temabase_mLuv1.1`, parece ser um tema personalizado, que alguém criou "para si mesmo" e que não o listou como disponível nos repositórios Wordpress ou em plataformas para venda de Temas Wordpress, o que tornou  a sua pesquisa um pouco mais complicada do que o normal, mas depois de algumas voltas, eu consegui encontrar esse tema.

Porém tanto o link do tema que adicionas-te como referência nos comentários para download deste tema, como o seu próprio código em si, aparentam ser diferentes daquilo que mencionas-te previamente nos comentários, daí a razão para a minha pesquisa deste tema como referi acima.

Ora bem, assumindo que o [tema seja este](http://madlyluv.com/extras/demos/?preview_theme=mLuv1.0), abaixo deste código do menu que envias-te:

```
<!-- menu-topo --> 
<div class="menu-topo">
    ...
</div>
<!-- fim menu-topo -->
```

Vais encontrar um código assim:

```
<!-- cabeçalho do blog -->
<div class="cabecalho">
    ...
</div>
<!-- fim cabeçalho do blog -->
```

O que tens que fazer aqui é **trocar a ordem destes scripts**, ou seja a **mover todo o bocado de código** a partir de - `<div class="cabecalho">` até ao final do encerramento desta tag - `<div>`, para antes, ou seja para cima do código - `<div class="menu-topo"> ... </div>`

Por outras palavras, o código **HTML** agora encontra-se desta maneira:
http://jsfiddle.net/vago08gk/

E tu vais ter que trocar a sua ordem de maneira a que eles fiquem assim:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjb1epdm/

> **Nota:** O código dentro da `<div class="cabecalho">` neste exemplo está em pleno HTML, mas no código do teu tema deve ter uma função em PHP, para gerar e disponibilizar uma imagem como `header` quando fizeres upload da mesma via `Dashboard` do teu Wordpress. **Não copies** este código deste exemplo e coles lá no teu tema ou essa função **deixará de funcionar**, em vez disso **corta e cola** mesmo o código **do teu tema** como explicado acima.

Comment: Consegui! Super obrigada, de verdade! Quebrou um suuuuper galho!

Comment: De nada @ThaísPietrobon , não existe melhor forma de dizer obrigado aqui no Stack Overflow que marcar a resposta como correta, ou votar positivamente nela =) Boa continuação de desenvolvimento.